# Fréchet derivative of an integral operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $F: L^1(\mathbb R, C(\mathbb R\times \mathbb R)) \rightarrow C(\mathbb R\times \mathbb R)$ be defined as: 
$$F(f)(a,y)
= y+ \int_0^a f(\tau-a, \tau,y) d\tau $$

where $f \in L^1(\mathbb R, C(\mathbb R \times \mathbb R))$.

Could I say something about the Fréchet differentiability of $F$ with respect to $f$?

Are there in general some conditions for an intergal operators to be differentiable ?

Comment: What are $L^1$ and $C$ here?

Comment: $C(\mathbb R \times \mathbb R)$ is the space of the continuous functions from $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$.                                                                                                                                                              $L^1(\mathbb R, C(\mathbb R \times \mathbb R))$ is the space of the functions $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow C(\mathbb R \times \mathbb R)$ that are integrable, hence such that $\int_{\mathbb R} |f(s)|_{C(\mathbb R\times \mathbb R)} ds < \infty$

Comment: Anyway, use differentiation under integral sign.

Comment: I tried to solve the exercise but it doesn't make much sense to me. You are abusing notation but not saying how. Also, derivatives in normed spaces are usually with respect to some norm (or seminorm), what are the seminorms you are thinking of?